# MS Access Pulling value from combobox in where condition using macro builder

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am trying to pull the value the user selects from a combo box in a `Where Condition` for a macro.  The Row Source for the combo box is a table where the first Column is the id numbers and the second Column is the data that the user chose.

I have tried both of the below statements with no luck

1) `[Query]![value]=[Forms]![Main Menu]![Combo]`

2)  `[Query]![value]=[Forms]![Main Menu]![Combo].[Column](1)`

Where `combo` is my combo box
The first one I know is pulling the ID number which is not what I want.  I have manually entered in a text box and found that if i set up my macro to match whats in the text box it will work correctly.

How can I pull whats on the second column instead of the combo box?

---

**EDIT**

The workaround I found was I now instead did an `after update` on the combo box to fill an invisible textbox, then i instead used that to pull the value I needed.

Such that:
`[Query]![value]=[Forms]![Main Menu]![textBox]`

Comment: Glad you found a workaround, but generally you can only access all properties (including additional columns of a ComboBox) using VBA. You could also have retrieved your value using a domain aggregate function, something like `=DLookUp("[DataField]", "MyTable", "[ID]=" & [Forms]![Main Menu]![Combo])`

Comment: I like that method better, Thank you!